# Cannot resolve SYMBOL при создании ENUM

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enum

Создал ENUM. Строку создания экземпляра `enum` подчеркивает красным и выдает ошибку!

```java
package com.company;

public class Main {

    enum CoffeSize {
        SMALL(500), MEDIUM(450), BIG(378);

        int mlltr;

        CoffeSize(int mlltr) {
            this.mlltr = mlltr;
        }

        int getMlltr() {
            return mlltr;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CoffeSize coffeSize = new CoffeSize.MEDIUM; // СТРОКА ПОДЧЕРНУТА И ПИШЕТ cannot resolve symbol MEDUIM
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял свою ошибку!
Синтаксическая ошибка:
при создании экземпляра `enum` слово `new` использовать не нужно.